# Apache - внезапно перестали работать виртуальные хосты

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

Apache2.4 (Win 10) - тестовая машина.

**Проблема:** внезапно перестали работать вирутальные хосты.

**Работает:** localhost, 127.0.0.1

**Не работает:** sitetest.com, test.com и.т.д

**Что делали:**

1. httpd.conf - меняли порты, не помогает
2. tcp/ip reset / flushdns
3. установили Denwer - работает localhost, 127.0.0.1, виртуальные хосты
   нет.
4. Firewall, skype (удален) antivirus - отключали

Наш вывод, что-то произошло в самой OS, так как виртуальные хосты не работают не на одном из установленных серверов.

Как выяснить пошагово где кроется проблема ?

Comment: Эти хосты реально существуют и пингуются?

Comment: нет, это локальные хосты. в файле hosts они в таком формате 127.0.0.1 site.com

Comment: Пинги на них идут? Если нет, то проверяйте файл `hosts`

Comment: Нет, пинг идет только на localhost, любой другой локальных хост, пытается обратится в интернет, т.е как мы понимаем он не привязан к 127.0.0.1. Но почему ? если в файле hosts он есть ? То есть, чтобы мы не создавали работает только localhost / 127.0.0.1 другие любые хосты как бы игнорируются и обращение идет в интернет

Comment: Проверьте файл `hosts` еще раз. Он мог измениться после вашей правки

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, проблему вызвало что-то, возможно сам сервер или какой-то сторонний софт. Файл hosts был неправильно перезаписал ! То есть визуально он без ошибок синтакса и.т.д  Но его свойства или права были как-то изменены, в итоге сервер/система его читает и видит, но работать с ним по каким-то причинам не может. Решилось все удаление и пересозданием файла hosts